# How can I make the browser read "%0A" as a just string, not encoded character

Tags: html, url, uri, encode

I'm facing a problem with URI in my web service.

One of my webpage has a link to another page like "http://aaa.com/abc.jsp?columns=abc,%0abcd" using get method.

When the browser(Chrome) opens the page "http://aaa.com/abc.jsp?columns=abc,%0abcd",
it reads "%0a" as LF(The browser thinks "%0a" is encoded) even though "%0abcd" is itself a string.

Is there any solution to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answers your question: [URI encode, Percent-encoding the percent character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character).

Basically, when you put your string into your URL, just encode the `%` sign as `%25`, it should be properly converted.